# Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single host

Tags: cisco, switch

I've got this error and feeling frustrated about it , So we have in Production areas machine that's needs to assign to vlan 213 and after i did the configuration for that port and got an error with spanning-tree portfast , so i took it off from that port, can some let me know i did a right thing when i took it off? or should i leave it in the configuration ?
[image]

```
BLDG-C-North-Product(config-if)#switchport mode access
BLDG-C-North-Product(config-if)#spanning-tree portfast
%Warning: portfast should only be enabled on ports connected to a single
host. Connecting hubs, concentrators, switches, bridges, etc... to this
interface  when portfast is enabled, can cause temporary bridging loops.
Use with CAUTION



%Portfast has been configured on GigabitEthernet3/0/16 but will only
have effect when the interface is in a non-trunking mode.
```

Answer (score 4):

Those are "cautionary" messages.  They are not telling you that you've done something wrong, but telling you things you should/should not do.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you Sir , it's make sense for me now i was afraid of it, The company i work with they did not tell me how or what needs to add to the port configuration, I got confuse and feel lost sometimes special i'm tire1 , RSM used to do all the configuration and still. @RonTrunk